# How do I combine a Pino transport with a formatter?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, logging

I am trying to pass my logs through Pino and format them with the ecs formatter and then send them to a tcp transporter. However, I have no idea how to combine those two functions.

In the ecs formatter docs ([here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@elastic/ecs-pino-format)), it shows passing the formatter to Pino on initialization as the first param like so:

```
const log = pino(ecsFormat())
```

But in the TCP transporter it also shows passing the transport to the Pino initialization as the first param! ([docs here](https://github.com/pinojs/pino-socket))

```
const log = pino(transport)
```

But those functions are not mutually exclusive. How in the world do I format my logs and THEN transport them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`pino()`](https://github.com/pinojs/pino/blob/master/docs/api.md#pino-transport) function takes an `options` and `destination` argument, both optional.

As [`ecs-pino-format` returns pino config](https://github.com/elastic/ecs-logging-nodejs/blob/08cbec44c00aaeed2f27871d1766e89ac3847520/loggers/pino/index.js#L99) and you have already constructed the transport, specify both arguments

```
const log = pino(ecsFormat(), transport)
```

I don't believe this is the case for `ecs-pino-format`, but if the pino config happened to already specify a `transport` property, the config would need to be modified as it takes precedence over the second `destination` argument

```
const ecs_options = ecsFormat()
const pino_config = { 
  ...ecs_options,
  transport: {
     ...ecs_options.transport,
     my_override: 'whatever',
  }
}
const log = pino(pino_config)
```